# How to align text in a way it starts from a margin in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How do i make the login text and sign in text to start from a single margin rather than the alignment it is shown in the picture?

[image]

Here the text isnt being aligned from a single margin and has off placement between texts

Code for it:

```
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 200,
                ),
                const Divider(
                  thickness: 3,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  indent: 160,
                  endIndent: 160,
                ),
                Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(32, 32, 32, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(8),
                    ),
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Login',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 32,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                'Sign in to continue',
                                style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(161, 161, 161, 1),
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the crossAxisAlignment property of the Column to start:

```
child: Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    ...]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: should be crossAxisAlignment.

Set the `mainAxisAlignment` attribute for the `Column`:

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    ...
```

Comment: I think it's actually `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,`

Answer (score 0):

Add CrossAxisAlignment.start to immediate parent column of text.

```
Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                              child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, //here
                                children: [
                                
                                  Text(
                                    'Login',
                                   
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Sign in to continue',
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
```